# R CMD check note: Non-standard files/directories found at top level (PNG file)

Tags: r, devtools

When I run `R CMD check` via `devtools::check()`, I get the following NOTE:

Non-standard files/directories found at top level:
  `‘README-unnamed-chunk-3-1.png’ ‘README-unnamed-chunk-4-1.png’`

This is a file generated by knitting the `README.rmd` file. How can I address this note? The source for the package is [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/tidyLPA).

Comment: By using the `.Rbuildignore` file, see [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).

Comment: You could also move the figures out of the package root into a more suitable location by setting the figure directory, eg: `opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "inst/figs/")`