# R CMD build versus devtools::build() (Non-standard file/directory found at top level)

Tags: r, devtools

I am writing an R package and build and test it with:

```
Rscript -e "devtools::document()" && R CMD build . && Rscript -e "devtools::test();devtools::check()"
```

I get a note:

```
checking top-level files
   Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
     ‘PosteriorBootstrap_0.0.1.tar.gz’
```

I get the note whether `devtools::check()` comes first or second.

[This
thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-CMD-check-Note-Non-standard-file-found-at-top-level-td4675278.html) suggests:

> The note is telling you that you usually shouldn't have a file called
>   build in the top level of your package.

The `tar.gz` file is created by `R CMD build` and I get the same error even if I delete it before running it.

[This
thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600293/r-cmd-check-note-non-standard-files-directories-found-at-top-level-png-file)
suggests adding the `tar.gz` file to `.Rbuildinore`, which removes the note.

Another way to remove it is to run everything from devtools:

```
Rscript -e "devtools::document(); devtools::build(); devtools::load_all('.'); devtools::test(); devtools::check()"
```

And then I don't get that note.

What's the difference between `R CMD build` and `devtools::build()` and why does the former throw that note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are combining a number of steps that perform similar and/or competing functions. I would suggest reading [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html) for a best-practice `build` and `check` workflow.

When you run `R CMD build` it builds the package to the current directory, which is the top level package directory. Therefore, when you run your checks, it sees the .tar.gz file in the package root, which is a non-standard file to have in a package, thus the warning. `devtools::build()` is smart and builds the package to the package **parent** directory (regardless of where you are calling it from). Trying to call `R CMD` commands mixed with `devtools` functions can create issues, because `devtools` also calls `R CMD` commands, so you may be duplicating actions at various points in time or causing commands to be called in the incorrect order.

Per the link above, a best-practice workflow would be:

```
Rscript -e "devtools::document();devtools::check();devtools::build()"
```

called from the package root, and you avoid dealing with `R CMD` altogether. If you want to use `R CMD` it would look something like this:

```
Rscript -e "devtools::document()" && cd .. && R CMD build PosteriorBootstrap && R CMD check PosteriorBootstrap*.tar.gz
```

starting in the package root and then changing to the parent directory.